# How can I get the IActionContextAccessor from the Endpoint.RequestDelegate when using Endpoint Routing and MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a asp .net core 3.1 application and have configured MVC and Endpoint Routing. Assume I have an Endpoint object (it won't always be the Endpoint associated with the current request), I then have it's RequestDelegate. I'd like to get the IActionContextAccessor from this RequestDelegate. In the following example, when I'm in debug mode I can see the _actionContextAccessor so I know it's there.

```
var endpoint = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();
```

[image]

I'm sure you'd like more context of what I'm doing and I can give you more if you like but the gist of this question is to assume I have an Endpoint object and I'm configured to use MVC, how can I get the IActionContextAccessor?

**UPDATE**

What I'm ultimately trying to get is the actions parameters. Just the type of the input parameters. We follow a one input model convention so actually what I want is that one input model's type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the type of an action's parameters, there's no need to use `IActionContextAccessor` or the `ActionContext` property it exposes. An `Endpoint` instance contains a set of metadata: for an endpoint that represents an action, this contains an instance of `ActionDescriptor`, which, unsurprisingly, describes an action. One of its properties is `Parameters`, which exposes the set of parameters for that action.

Putting that all together, here's an example of how to get to the type of a single action parameter, as requested:

```
var actionDescriptor = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ActionDescriptor>();

if (actionDescriptor != null)
{
    var actionParameterType = actionDescriptor.Parameters.SingleOrDefault()?.ParameterType;

    // ...
}
```